# Cannot access window variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React Redux app. The base template for my React app is something like

```
 <div id="react"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/main-hash.js" ></script>
 <script>
   window.userData = {a: 1, b:2}
 </script>
```

I want to use the variable `userData` in my react app. `window.userData` returns undefined at almost all places (reducers, componentDidMount of a component etc.). But if I log the window object, I can see in my console that there is a `userData` variable in it.

To sum it up `console.log(window, window.userData)` returns -

`Window undefined` where Window in which window is a collapsed tree. Uncollapsing it, the userData variable can be seen in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move your script tag before your react component script tag. It should work.

I mean you should create userData member in windows object before you use it.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 <div id="react"></div>
 <script>window.userData = {a: 1, b:2}</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/main-hash.js" ></script>
```